# Logo aparece detrás del background - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con ReactJs y quiero hacer un fondo con un gradiente de rojo a blanco y encima va a ir un logo.

Estoy usando MUI y en las `sx` prop puse lo de abajo pero me aparece el logo detrás del gradient ***(background)*** en cambio sí lo coloco en un fondo normal de un solo color ***(backgroundColor)*** si me aparece el logo delante.

```
<Grid
  item
  xs={false}
  sm={4}
  md={20}
  sx={{
      backgroundImage: 'url(https://...)',
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
      //backgroundColor: 'linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(195,34,34,1) 0%, rgba(249,249,249,1) 100%)'//Logo detras
      background: "#D52323", //Logo delante
      backgroundSize: '100%',
      backgroundPosition: 'center',
   }}
/>            
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando hablamos de css el orden de las propiedades importa, cuando usas propiedades individuales el orden es de arriba hacia abajo quedando como prioridad la de mas abajo y cuando usas una sola propiedad (background) el orden es de izquierda a derecha quedando como prioritaria la de la izquierda, esto es cuando ocupas comas para definir las distintas opciones, en este caso, distintos backgrounds, pero si no ocupas comas, se aplican todos los backgrounds en orden, te dejo un último ejemplo que creo es lo que buscas hacer (ver en página completa)

```css
.example-class {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(195,34,34, 1) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 100%);
  background-image: url('https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/La-primera-imagen-de-la-historia-770x413.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.example-class2 {
  background-image: url('https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/La-primera-imagen-de-la-historia-770x413.jpg');
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(195,34,34, 1) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.example-class3 {
  background: url('https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/La-primera-imagen-de-la-historia-770x413.jpg'), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(195,34,34, 1) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.example-class4 {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(195,34,34, 1) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 100%), url('https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/La-primera-imagen-de-la-historia-770x413.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.gradientArribaTransparente-imagenAbajo {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(195,34,34, 0.8) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.8) 100%), url('https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/La-primera-imagen-de-la-historia-770x413.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.loQueBuscas {
  background-image: url('https://www.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/La-primera-imagen-de-la-historia-770x413.jpg'), linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(195,34,34, 1) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 1) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-class"></div>
<div class="example-class2"></div>
<div class="example-class3"></div>
<div class="example-class4"></div>
<div class="gradientArribaTransparente-imagenAbajo"></div>

<div class="loQueBuscas"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias @LPZadkiel me sirvió tu respuesta, ahora tengo otra duda. Tengo que hacer otra pregunta o puedo agregarlo aquí?

Comment: edité la respuesta agregando creo el resultado que estás buscando (ejemplo 5, página completa para ver bien el resultado)